# when I use For loop, key pass the next step. while the foreach data did not changed data.PHP

Tags: php, laravel

This is my function, which to calculate the intersection time range of two people. when I use three loops, the first loop could pass the key to the next step, but the data they used belong to other people's data. I am very confused.

public function test()
{

```
    //choose records of viva arrangement
    $records = DB::table('application_student')
        ->where('allocationStatus', '=', 1)
        ->select('user_id', 'supervisor_id', 'assessor_id')
        ->get()->toArray();

    //single records
    foreach ($records as $key => $record) {
        $viva[] = [
            $sup_id = $record->supervisor_id, // key 0=>supervisor
            $stu_id = $record->user_id,       // key 1=>student
        ];
    }

    // $x is the key number of viva[]
    for ($x = 0; $x <count($records); $x++){

        $sup_id = $viva[$x][0]; //supervisor_id of record $x
        $stu_id = $viva[$x][1]; //student_id of record $x

        //find availability of supervisor
        $sup_time = DB::table('time_allocates')
            ->where('user_id','=',$sup_id)
            ->select('start','end')->get()->toArray();

        //find availability of student
        $stu_time = DB::table('time_allocates')
            ->where('user_id','=',$stu_id)
            ->select('start','end')->get()->toArray();

        //every single availability of supervisor
        foreach ($sup_time as $key => $supT) {
            $sup[] = [
                $s1 = strtotime($supT->start), //key 0=>start time
                $e1 = strtotime($supT->end), //key 1=>end time
            ];
        }

        //every single availability of student
        foreach ($stu_time as $key => $stuT) {
            $stu[] = [
                $s2 = strtotime($stuT->start), //key 0=>start time
                $e2 = strtotime($stuT->end),   //key 1=>end time
            ];
        }

        //$i is the key number of single supervisor availability record
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($sup_time); $i++) {
            //$j is the key number of single student availability record
            for ($j = 0; $j < count($stu_time); $j++) {

                echo "$x+'$i'+'$j <br>";
                $sup_s1 = $sup[$i][0]; // start time of supervisor
                $sup_e1 = $sup[$i][1]; // end time of supervisor
                $stu_s2 = $stu[$j][0]; // start time of student
                $stu_e2 = $stu[$j][1]; // end time of student

                //make sure the time range of student between supervisor has intersection
                if($stu_s2>=$sup_s1 && $sup_e1>$stu_s2){
                    $start = $stu_s2;
                    if ($sup_e1<=$stu_e2){
                        $end = $sup_e1;
                    }else{
                        $end =$stu_e2;
                    }
                    if ($end-$start>=3600){
                        $start_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $start);
                        $end_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $end);
                        echo "$start_date '-' $end_date -$stu_id -$sup_id<br>";
                    }

                }elseif ($sup_s1>=$stu_s2 && $sup_e1>$stu_s2){
                    $start =$sup_s1;
                    if ($sup_e1<=$stu_e2){
                        $end=$sup_e1;
                    }else{
                        $end=$stu_e2;
                    }
                    if ($end-$start>=3600){
                        $start_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $start);
                        $end_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $end);
                        echo "$start_date '-' $end_date -$stu_id-$sup_id <br>";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is the result of the window. the student id changed from 2 to 3, but the data use the 2 always. please help me, guys.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYOHe.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not reinitializing `$sup` for each loop.

```php
$sup[] = [
    $s1 = strtotime($supT->start), //key 0=>start time
    $e1 = strtotime($supT->end), //key 1=>end time
];
```

Same for `$stu[]`
for the second student, it will add the data on top of those of the first one.

You need to do it like this

```php
//every single availability of supervisor
$sup = [];
foreach ($sup_time as $key => $supT) {
    $sup[] = [
        $s1 = strtotime($supT->start), //key 0=>start time
        $e1 = strtotime($supT->end), //key 1=>end time
    ];
}

//every single availability of student
$stu = [];
foreach ($stu_time as $key => $stuT) {
    $stu[] = [
        $s2 = strtotime($stuT->start), //key 0=>start time
        $e2 = strtotime($stuT->end),   //key 1=>end time
    ];
}
```

PS: you have a lot of redundant code and many extra loops to remove.

Comment: Sir, thanks for your help. thanks for your willingness to reading my poor English. To be honest, this is my first time writing a piece of code. I am a student, there are many problems I have. I am trying to learn more. this is an amazing forum.

Comment: @ZIHANGYU no problem, if you want some help, hit me up on my email (profile)